# I can't absorb Dragon souls

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I have all the Skyrim DLCs, and a few mods. I can't do the original quest and I can't do shouts (which is really annoying).

I killed the dragon Dumviir (or something like that) in the quest where the Jarl of Whiterun sends you to kill said dragon. But I can't absorb it's dragon soul.

I killed it and all the guards say "she must be Dragonborn!" and they all look scared, but nothing happens. I have all the unofficial patches (skyrim, dawnguard, hearthfire, dragonborn and high res) and SMPC (aka USKP addon) installed but they didn't fix it.

Has anyone else had similar issues?

Comment: Have you confirmed the mods aren't causing the problem, by backing up your save(s) and disabling the plugins?

Comment: @ VaishaliI have it on Xbox as well, it's just i don't have the DLC's on that :). 
it's the latest Patch version
@sevensideddie I'm fairly sure they're not the problem, but i'll unistall them all and get back to you :)

Comment: Can you edit in your mod load order in the question? [BOSS](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/6/?) can help you with listing and optimizing your load order. The issue you described could possibly be caused by putting your mods in the wrong load order. See my [answer in this related question, "Why can't I absorb a dragon soul?"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/115650/4797) - for more info.

Comment: About SMPC, you might want to read this post by Arthmoor (one of the USKP developers) about it: [So You Want to Know What's Wrong with SMPC.esp? (The Skyrim Misc Patches Collection - aka USKP_AddOn)](http://afkmods.iguanadons.net/index.php?/topic/3719-the-skyrim-misc-patches-collection-aka-uskp-addon/)

Comment: I use boss :). it has to be one of my mods cause I took them all off and i absorbed the soul :/. could it be one of the "patches"?

Comment: But, it won't let me absorb in a save game where I already killed dumvnir

Comment: It's unlikely to be a patch, unless you have out-of-date patches (since they have had bugs in the past). (Though it could be SMPC, since it's not well made.) So, standard procedure to isolate the problem is to install the mods a few at a time until it breaks again, then add & remove until it's narrowed down to one mod.

Comment: You probably can't absorb Dumvir's soul on that save because the problem is already saved, probably because the soul wasn't added to the skeleton and the trigger to add it is past. If you have a save before the battle, that *should* be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put the unofficial dragonborn patch after the unofficial skyrim patch in your load order - I had a problem with absorbing souls after installing dragon born, which required the UDP to be included.

See: [Why can't I absorb a dragon soul?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/115648/why-cant-i-absorb-a-dragon-soul)